# Can you enumerate links in C# that pass attributes to a method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a directory for our website in C#/ASP.NET. I already have the ability to search by name and position when you type it in a textbox.  I want to add the functionality of searching by the first letter of the last name or by clicking on positions.

I wanted to create my array of letters an links as such:

```
protected void displayAlphabet() {
    char[] az =
        Enumerable.Range('a', 'z' - 'a' + 1).Select(i => (Char)i).ToArray();
    foreach (var c in az)
    {
        Response.Write(
            "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"domainQuery(" + c + ")\">" + c + "</a>"
        );
        if (c.ToString() != "z")
        {
            Response.Write("-");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on DataBinding and something like the [`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx) control.

Check out the [Data Controls section on ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/web-forms).